# How do I pour the wine in the correct order using the glyphs?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

All this wine is making me sick, I'm trying to work the cellar glyphs:

[image]

I've poured every type of wine in, but every single one hurt me. Checking the wiki, it says:

> To determine the order of the wine to pour, look at the three glyphs that are around the center big glyph. Each of these corresponds to a wine and you need to pour three wines into the drain pipe in the order corresponding to the glyphs on the top, lower left, and then lower right.

It also says:

> If wines are poured in the wrong order, the assignment of glyphs to bottles may reset. In other words, if the snake glyph was assigned to Port before you erroneously poured, it might be reassigned to Muscat after.

It's going to take me forever to guess the correct sequence, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The dropdown for choosing a bottle to pour has a magnifying glass with which you can inspect the bottles. The bottles have the glyphs on them, so you simple have to look through for the ones that correspond to the glyphs. *You must be wearing Lord Spookyraven's spectacles in order to see the glyphs.*

You can also just inspect the bottles normally in your inventory to see the glyphs.

Comment: I'm pretty certain you need too have lord spookyraven's spectacles in your inventory to see the glyphs on the bottles, and during your first ascension you even need to have them equipped.

Comment: @Arperum You need the specs to even see the glyphs on the wall, I think...

Comment: Don't know about that part.